# How to change datatypes in tuples?

Tags: python, string, list, int, tuples

I'm working with a list of int's and floats, and trying to change the second parameter to string.

What I have is something like this:

```
array = [(12.0, 23),(9.0, 24)]
```

What I want is:

```
array = [(12.0, '23'),(9.0, '24')]
```

I tried using a simple for, as shown below:

```
for i in range(len(array)):
  array[i][1] == str(array[i][1])
```

Could anyone explain me why this does not work, and if so, an easier way to do this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: First, `==` is for comparison. Second, tuples are immutable, so you'd have to create a copy of each with different values.

Comment: Tuples are immutable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are immutable so you can't just change them. You need to make new ones. Probably easiest with a list comprehension:

```
array = [(12.0, 23),(9.0, 24)]

array = [(a, str(b)) for a,b in array]
# [(12.0, '23'), (9.0, '24')]
```

If you need to alter the list in place, you can, but you still need new tuples:

```
array = [(12.0, 23),(9.0, 24)]

for i, (a,b) in enumerate(array):
    array[i] = (a, str(b))

array
# (12.0, '23'), (9.0, '24')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> array = [(12.0, 23),(9.0, 24)]
>>> [(x[0],str(x[1])) for x in array]
[(12.0, '23'), (9.0, '24')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[tuple(map(str, xs)) for xs in lst]
[('12.0', '23',) , ('9.0', '24')]

result = []
    for xs in lst:
     temp = []
      for x in xs:
         temp.append(str(x))
      result.append(tuple(temp))



result
```

By the way tuples are something that cannot be changed i.e immutable

Answer (score 0):

Creating new tuples (as suggested in other answers) is usually the right approach in this situation, but if you also need to preserve the list items' identities (if you have references to them elsewhere), you could instead switch from tuples to lists:

```
>>> array = [[12.0, 23], [9.0, 24]]
>>> for i in range(len(array)):
...     array[i][1] = str(array[i][1])
...
>>> array
[[12.0, '23'], [9.0, '24']]
>>>
```

Note, however, that since you're accessing elements with literal indices ("`[1]`"), tuples are probably the more semantically correct type to use. You'd need to weigh that consideration against the mutability benefit of lists.

Answer (score 0):

That is because Lists are mutable however Tuples are immutable. Immutable meaning that they can’t be changed once they have been assigned.
Also string, float, integer are all immutable python data structure.
please refer to the below link for more information about List vs Tuple differences.

https://realpython.com/python-lists-tuples/